# What are the racial traits for mind-flayers?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, monsters

I'm planning on making a Mind-flayer character for D&D 5e and need their traits. I need to know special abilities, stat modifiers, and other things needed for character creation. A site that provides this would also be useful.

Answer (score 14):

There are no official stats for mind flayers as player characters, for what are probably obvious reasons. However, if your DM is on-board with this character concept, have them create the race's PC stats/traits using the rules in the DMG on pages 285–7.

If your DM is not on-board with the idea of an illithid PC, you're out of luck — for custom things like new races, the DM's decision generally stands.